# Using a formula with Statsmodels of scipy - Python

Tags: python, formula, linear-regression, statsmodels

I am building a straightforward regression model with statsmodels using a formula but I am getting an error which I do not understand.

For a reproducible example my dataframe is Prices:

```
Prices.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 25 entries, 2012-06-30 to 2018-06-30
Freq: Q-DEC
Data columns (total 4 columns):
FB                    25 non-null float64
GOOG                  25 non-null float64
GDP_growth            25 non-null float64
GDP_growth_shifted    24 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(4)
memory usage: 1000.0 bytes

Prices.to_json() 
'{"FB":{"1341014400000":35.26,"1348963200000":31.9133333333,"1356912000000":24.76,"1364688000000":25.43,"1372550400000":27.6966666667,"1380499200000":29.8733333333,"1388448000000":42.2733333333,"1396224000000":54.78,"1404086400000":61.9233333333,"1412035200000":64.54,"1419984000000":72.7233333333,"1427760000000":77.42,"1435622400000":80.87,"1443571200000":83.9333333333,"1451520000000":90.2466666667,"1459382400000":100.8266666667,"1467244800000":106.8833333333,"1475193600000":116.6166666667,"1483142400000":122.8233333333,"1490918400000":125.43,"1498780800000":135.3733333333,"1506729600000":152.3233333333,"1514678400000":166.5233333333,"1522454400000":174.9033333333,"1530316800000":172.17},"GOOG":{"1341014400000":306.6033333333,"1348963200000":312.19,"1356912000000":338.7,"1364688000000":363.36,"1372550400000":396.7433333333,"1380499200000":428.11,"1388448000000":459.26,"1396224000000":520.9766666667,"1404086400000":568.72,"1412035200000":556.0,"1419984000000":565.0566666667,"1427760000000":535.56,"1435622400000":536.8866666667,"1443571200000":560.1466666667,"1451520000000":627.9,"1459382400000":709.6133333333,"1467244800000":738.7766666667,"1475193600000":743.08,"1483142400000":771.7733333333,"1490918400000":801.2033333333,"1498780800000":843.9766666667,"1506729600000":915.2533333333,"1514678400000":964.72,"1522454400000":1036.6966666667,"1530316800000":1083.77},"GDP_growth":{"1341014400000":1.7,"1348963200000":0.5,"1356912000000":0.5,"1364688000000":3.6,"1372550400000":0.5,"1380499200000":3.2,"1388448000000":3.2,"1396224000000":-1.0,"1404086400000":5.1,"1412035200000":4.9,"1419984000000":1.9,"1427760000000":3.3,"1435622400000":3.3,"1443571200000":1.0,"1451520000000":0.4,"1459382400000":1.5,"1467244800000":2.3,"1475193600000":1.9,"1483142400000":1.8,"1490918400000":1.8,"1498780800000":3.0,"1506729600000":2.8,"1514678400000":2.3,"1522454400000":2.2,"1530316800000":4.1},"GDP_growth_shifted":{"1341014400000":0.5,"1348963200000":0.5,"1356912000000":3.6,"1364688000000":0.5,"1372550400000":3.2,"1380499200000":3.2,"1388448000000":-1.0,"1396224000000":5.1,"1404086400000":4.9,"1412035200000":1.9,"1419984000000":3.3,"1427760000000":3.3,"1435622400000":1.0,"1443571200000":0.4,"1451520000000":1.5,"1459382400000":2.3,"1467244800000":1.9,"1475193600000":1.8,"1483142400000":1.8,"1490918400000":3.0,"1498780800000":2.8,"1506729600000":2.3,"1514678400000":2.2,"1522454400000":4.1,"1530316800000":null}}'
```

My code is :

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols

result = sm.ols(formula="FB ~ GOOG + GDP_growth", data=Price.tail(-1)).fit()

PatsyError: Error evaluating factor: NameError: name 'GDP_growth' is not defined
    FB ~ GOOG + GDP_growth
                ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Did you try to remove underscore in column name?

Comment: what does `print(*map(repr, Price.columns))` give you?

Comment: Could it be that you have a dataframe called `Price` with no column `'GDP_growth'`? Because the dataset you showed is called `Prices`, not `Price` and when I try your formula with that dataset (`data=Prices.tail(-1)`), it works